# Email sent by PHP doesn't have a date

Tags: php, email

I have two questions about php's mail() function doesn't appear to have a date?
Whenever I open my webmail (one.com's squirrel mail) all mails sent to myself using php's mail() (I'm testing a system I'm developing) is always received today, sometimes later today = in the future.

Also, when opening the mails in Thunderbird it shows up as html-mail, but when opening them in the webmail or on my Galaxy S3, there's no markup, just plain text and a "-" in the first line?

My headers are:

```
$headers = "From: ***.dk <noreply@***.dk> \n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@***.dk \n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

and the html in the beginning and the end are:

```
const init = <<<'END_OF_STRING'
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <html>  
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://***.dk/development/stylesheets/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://***.dk/development/stylesheets/front.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="pageWrap">
    <a href="http://***.dk/development/?page=home"><div id="header">&nbsp;</div></a>
    <div id="descriptionText">
END_OF_STRING;

const theend = <<<'END_OF_STRING'
    <!--descriptionText--></div>
    <!--pageWrap--></div>
    </body>
END_OF_STRING;
```

Thanks in advance!:D

Comment: I checked my PHP mail, it has a Date. I suspect it's added by the local mail server software, not PHP.

Comment: Where do you show the date in your code?

Comment: you can, but you don't need to, add the date header `"Date: ".date("r")."\r\n"` otherwise the server dae is used, Dont mess with the date, it use to be a spammers trick  so can get you black listed fast

Comment: But the weird thing is, that as a result, these emails are always on the top of my inbox- it's quite annoying. My phone provider has the same problem in their newsletters, which annoys me so much, the I'm quite certain it'll annoy users of our system as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first two lines to:

```
$headers = "From: ***.dk <noreply@***.dk> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@***.dk \r\n";
```

You left out `\r`.

Regarding the problem with HTML email, you need to simplify it. Many mail readers ignore sections like `<head>` and CSS links. If you google "html email css" you'll find some information on how to create HTML emails that will render consistently across a variety of systems.

Comment: I did that trying to get the html to work, originally they were there. That's not the error..

Comment: Your note about <head> is great, now I just need to figure out how to put one image behind another without using css background :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put the date at the end of the mail with: `echo date(DATE_RFC822);`? Some people actually do this.

Comment: @Dagon ow sorry my bad. Didn't really understand the question.